# How to write football ranking system algorithm

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I'm now developing football website and trying to write coding for ranking table. I feel that there must be algorithm to develop ranking table as follow.

[image]

And table structure is,

```
tb_result
-   matchno
-   team1
-   team2
-   score1
-   score2
```

And I'll input data just like

```
Matchno team1       team2       score1      score2
1       A-Team      B-Team          1       3
1       C-Team      D-Team          3       0
2       D-Team      A-Team          3       3
2       B-Team      C-Team          2       5
```

So I'd like to know any algorithm or formula can be developed to get ranking table.

Comment: mysql <> sql server. what are you using? sql server or mysql. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try to google on how teams are ranked in EPL?

Comment: currently using mysql server.

Comment: The algorithm exists, it's called "patience"

Comment: what will be the output data like @ppshein

Comment: What is score1 and score2; are they scores from separate games?

Comment: @mohan111 output is in my post (Picture).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils score1 and score2 are; 1-0 ... 2-0... 1-1... 2-1. If you're football fan, you must have known. It's goal, dude.

Comment: you don't even need to be a soccer fan (i'm definitely not).  Would `matchno` not more realistically be `roundno` tho? a match is between two teams, there aren't two different games between four different teams in a single match, no?

Comment: The question wasn't what a goal or score is but what do they represent. Are they scores from individual games. I was asking in terms of the table structure which could be better than repetitious columns.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before - although I don't know for certain whether SO already has an answer. Anyway, here's an answer - possibly quite similar to pala's. Incidentally, the rules for ranking ties get viciously complicated, but this should get you started: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 'simple' query to do what you want, with the table structure you have given.

That said it's quite possible.  You need a query for getting the total goals for for each team:

```
select team, sum(score1) score_for
         from
           (select team1 as team, score1
              from matches
            union all
            select team2, score2
              from matches
           ) qq
         group by team
```

Then you need pretty much the same query again to get goals against:

```
select team1 as team, sum(score2) score_against
         from
           (select team1, score2
              from matches
            union all
            select team2, score1
              from matches
           ) qq
        group by team
```

We just get the opposite score to what we retrieved in the first query.

It's also possible to combine these two queries into a single query:

```
select team, sum(score_for), sum(score_against)
from
(
  select team1 as team, score1 as score_for, score2 as score_against
    from matches
  union all
  select team2 as team, score2 as score_for, score1 as score_against
    from matches
)q
group by team;
```

We also need a query to count wins, losses and draws:

```
select team1 as team, count(case when result = 1 then result end) w, count(case when result = 0 then result end) d, count(case when result = -1 then result end) l
       from
         (select team1, case when score1 > score2 then 1 when score1 = score2 then 0 else -1 end result
            from matches
          union all
          select team2, case when score2 > score1 then 1 when score2 = score1 then 0 else -1 end result
            from matches
         ) qq
       group by team1
```

We use conditional aggregation there to assign a value to win, loss and draw (1, -1 and 0 respectively)

Lastly, we need a count of games played for each team.

```
select team, count(*) gp
       from 
        (select team1 as team
           from matches
         union all
         select team2 as team
           from matches
        ) qq
       group by team
```

It's also possible to get this value from any of the preceding queries, i've just separated it, as with the goals for/goals against to show a thought process.  In production, you would definitely want to combine them to increase performance.

In all cases here, we have to perform a `union`, because a team can appear in either team1, or team2, and we need to homogenise that. It is something that wouldnt be necessary with a different table schema, but that's another thing altogether.

Lastly, all we need to do is join all of these together and add a ranking, which we can do quite simply, because they conveniently all have a `team` column.  For convenience, i've assumed you have a `teams` table, if you don't, well that's just silly.

Anyway:

```
select  @rank := @rank + 1 as '#', q.*
from (
select teams.team, gp, score_for gf, score_against ga, score_for - score_against gd, w, l, d, (w * 3) + d as pts
  from  teams
    inner join
      (select team, sum(score1) score_for
         from
           (select team1 as team, score1
              from matches
            union all
            select team2, score2
              from matches
           ) qq
         group by team
       ) q1
       on teams.team = q1.team
    inner join
      (select team1 as team, sum(score2) score_against
         from
           (select team1, score2
              from matches
            union all
            select team2, score1
              from matches
           ) qq
        group by team
     ) q2
     on teams.team = q2.team
   inner join
     (select team1 as team, count(case when result = 1 then result end) w, count(case when result = 0 then result end) d, count(case when result = -1 then result end) l
       from
         (select team1, case when score1 > score2 then 1 when score1 = score2 then 0 else -1 end result
            from matches
          union all
          select team2, case when score2 > score1 then 1 when score2 = score1 then 0 else -1 end result
            from matches
         ) qq
       group by team1
     ) q3
     on teams.team = q3.team
   inner join
     (select team, count(*) gp
       from 
        (select team1 as team
           from matches
         union all
         select team2 as team
           from matches
        ) qq
       group by team
     ) q4
     on teams.team = q4.team
   order by pts desc
) q, (select @rank := 0) z
```

This query also calculates your `points` for you. My assumption is

- win = 3 points
- loss = 0 points
- draw = 1 point

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6939d/15)

Comment: it will be got probably correct answer.

Comment: @ppshein just realised i missed the ranking. adding it in

Comment: I've put "order by pts" end of query and testing is fine.

Comment: @ppshein true, but for completeness i've added that to the answer, plus automatically calculating the ladder position and including that in the results.

Comment: Upvote for the patience :-)